# Book with two spacefaring cultures: mages and sorcerers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi book series. I remember the cover of one book in the series, it contained a female captain with an eye patch.

The series starts with her father and friends for the first series. Two space-faring cultures, one side has mages and other either warlocks or sorcerers. They fly in a modified cargo ship (kind of like the Falcon). The copilot is called a mage.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Kinda like this? http://www.goodshowsir.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Galaxy_Jane.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [*The Price of the Stars*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363059.The_Price_of_the_Stars) by Debra Doyle and James D. MacDonald.

> Freebooter at heart, spacer by trade, Beka Rosselin-Metadi doesn't want to hear about how her father whose rugged generalship held back the Mageworlds -- or her highborn mother whose leadership has held the galaxy together since. Beka pilots spacecraft -- as far from her famous family as possible.Then Beka's mother is assassinated on the Senate floor, and her father offers her the title to Warhammer, prize ship from his own freebooting youth -- if she agrees to deliver the assassins to him "off the books."
>
> Looking for assassins has a tendency to make assassins look for you. In doing so, Beka's arranged her own very public death and adopted a new identity; now all she has to do is leave a trail of kidnappings and corpses across five star systems, and blow the roof off the strongest private fortress in the galaxy.

It is the first book published of the [*Mageworlds*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53631-mageworlds) series. The galaxy has its own “Force” called the currents of power, and the Adepts (your warlocks/sorcerers?) and Mages both use the power differently.

[image: Cover of The Price of the Stars]

Comment: Can you provide any additional details that suggest similarity with the points made? Maybe a plot description, etc.

Comment: That’s it. Thank you very much.